# How to measure the output level of the sub out of an A/V receiver

Tags: amplifier, audio, multimeter, output

I want to measure the output level of the RCA subwoofer output jack of an A/V receiver.

How do I do that?

Should I use the DC Volt mode of my multimeter and stick the positive prove into the hole of the RCA jack and touch the outer metal tube of it with the negative probe?

Is it safe to touch/untouch the jack with the probes while the receiver is on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are looking for an audio voltage - in that case, you should set the meter to read AC Volts.  There will only be voltage there when there is significant low-frequency content in the sound that is playing.

It should be safe to connect the probes while the receiver is on - I expect that you will only measure a few volts - under a volt if it is "line level" to an amplifier in the subwoofer, more if feeding a passive speaker directly.

Comment: Yes, the signal from the subwoofer out in the A/V receiver is fed to LINE IN of an active subwoofer. Thank you for your answer. I'll start with the master volume of the receiver at min. (The output level is affected by the master volume setting.)

Comment: For repeatable results, probably you want to play an audio test track from a CD or DVD source.